# Rust Read_line 'expected struct string, found f64'

Tags: rust

I'm new in rust and stuck in the error below, and i could not find any clue on it. Anyone can point me out? I got no idea how to define the read_line in float.

.read_line(&mut fahrenheit)
|                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `String`, found `f64`

```
fn main(){
    println!("enter fahrenheit: ");
    //io::stdin() .read_line(&mut index) .expect("Failed to read line");
    let mut fahrenheit: f64 = 66.66;

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut fahrenheit)
        .expect("fail to read");


    
    let tempConvert = fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);
    println!("convert from {tempConvert}");
}

fn fahrenheitToCelsius(x: f64) -> f64{  
    let mut gt: f64;
    gt = (x - 32.00) * 5.00 / 9.00;
    gt
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`read_line` will read a string from stdin, and it needs a buffer to put it in, which is supposed to be argument you pass it. If, then, you want to convert it, it's your job: it won't do that on its own. Thus the type error. To achieve what you want, simply create a buffer, *then* `parse` it.

```rust
  let mut buffer = String::new();
  io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer).expect("Failed to read");
  let fahrenheit = buffer.trim().parse::<f64>().expect("Failed to parse as `f64'");
```

Note that in your code, the generic argument of `parse` might be left implicit since your `fahrenheitToCelsius` function might be enough for the compiler to figure out the type to perform the conversion to.